# Qt - does it make sense to call QTreeView::dataChanged() from within QTreeView::currentChanged()?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I have existing code that I'm modifying.

It derives a class, `MyTreeView`, from `QTreeview` and re-implements `currentChanged()`.

Does it make sense to call `dataChanged()` here? Since `currentChanged()` is only called when the selection changes, it seems to be pointless to call `dataChanged()`

```
class MyTreeView(QTreeView):
   def currentChanged(self, current, previous):
        #self.setCurrentIndex(current)
        logging.debug(f"on current index {current}, \
            object {QModelIndex.internalPointer(current)}")
        self.dataChanged(current,current)
        self.obj_changed_signal.emit(current)
```

Comment: It's unspecific, because the answer will be an opinion. Anyway here's my opinion. In general, it's a bad idea to call the ```dataChanged()``` inside the ```currentChanged()```, not only because it's meaningless but because calling ```dataChanged()``` is the responsibility of the implementation of the base class. But there may exists a part of code that depends on that. Why not remove it and test for a side effect.

Comment: @relent95 I did remove it (I’ve been doing this for all the things that don’t make sense) and as you said, there’s no difference.